# How to deploy application to server instantly?

Tags: java, jrebel

Currently i am using trail version of Jrebel for instance deployment like any changes i am
making to my coding i needn't to restart the server to reflect the changes, Jrebel do it
for me .

what is Jrebel ?

A Java development-time tool that decreases turnaround by instantly reloading changes to your code, without having to restart the container or redeploy the application. Rebel integrates with the JVM and application servers mainly on the class loader level. It does not create any new class loaders, instead, it extends the existing ones with the ability to manage reloaded classes.

suggest any other method so that i can deploy my code instantly i needn't to redeploy again again.

Comment: Um... don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you asking for a replacement for `JRebel`?

Comment: I think he wants a server based on some script-based language, so you don't have to deploy anything, changes are reflected in real time :-)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  yeah i want replacement for jrebel as it is not free .

Comment: @loknath I'm not aware of any free drop in replacement. Either way, recommendations of tools are off topic here, sorry :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson   i found by stackoverflow a tool name Dynamic Code Evolution VM .is it good can i use it ?